# Animation Nodes - how to remove with python command

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, animation-nodes

As far as I know, you can run a command in the bar button to remove animation node trees. But I would like to automate this with another script, for rigging purposes.

This doesn't work:

```
bpy.ops.an.remove_node_tree("nodetreename")
```

As far as I know, there is an error Invoking the right window?

Any clue how to script this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it like so:

```
bpy.data.node_groups.remove(bpy.data.node_groups["tree name"])
```